# What is the most easiest way to configure between AWS server and custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to hand shaking between my AWS server and domain. I purchased my domain from godday.com. Any one can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create the static ip of the ec2 instance this is because ec2 ip is volatile every time you restarts ec2 the ip will change .In that case you have to create a static ip so follow the below step Login to your amaazon aws console then :

```
1.On EC2 Management console you will have a vertical menu on the left hand side.
2.Under “NETWORK & SECURITY” group click on “Elastic IPs”.
3.On the top menu you will see a blue button “Allocate New Address” click on it.
4.Just be sure “EIP used in” is set to “EC2” then click “Yes, Allocate”.
5.A new IP address will be created on the table, select it by clicking on the empty square by the left of the name.
6.Now click on “Associate Address” on the pop-up click on instance and select the instance you would like to associate to this IP.
7.Finally click “Associate” and that’s it. For now to access via SSH, FTP, etc. you will need to use the new elastic IP.
```

Next you need to point the static ip to the Godaddy domain name. Login to godaddy account:

```
1.Login into your godaddy account.
2.Under the upper menu click “Domains” and then click “Manage my Domains”.
3.Select the domain you would like to change by clicking the link to the domain on the table under “Domain Name” column.
4.In Domain Details there are three tabs, you should click on “DNS Zone File”.
5.Under A(Host) , click on “Edit Record (pick the one which is "@")” at the end in “Actions” column.
6.Now change the value on the field “Points to” with the elastic ip of your amazon ec2 instance.
```

Hope that helps you.